# Unable to execute configuration on router through TFTP's python script

Tags: dhcp, tftp

I am trying to use the ZTP approach to configure my router [R2]. My Ubuntu machine is both DHCP and TFTP server.

Ubuntu [DHCP Server]: 16.04.5 LTS
Cisco Router [DHCP Client]: 7200, version 15.2(4)S5

This is the python script- ztp.py.  ztp.py is stored in `/var/lib/tftpboot/`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5.2

import time
import cli

time.sleep(200)
print ("\n\n *** ZTP Day 0 Configuation *** \n\n")

fn = open('TXJla-outgoing/R1.txt','r')
fn.seek(0)
c =fn.readlines()
fn.close()

cli.configurep([c])
```

The configuration on `dhcpd.conf` for host R2 is -

```
host R2 {
  hardware ethernet CA:02:3B:E3:00:08;
  fixed-address 198.51.100.5;
  option bootfile-name !<opt 67> "/ztp.py";
  option tftp-server-name !<opt 150> "198.51.100.2";
}
```

The configuration is not exected on the Router. Please help resolve.

Answer (score 0):

In my setup (Cisco device as DHCP server, and debian as tftp)I did not needed the option 150.

Code on the CiscoDHCPServer:

```
   ip dhcp pool ztp
       network "networkip" "SNM"   
       default-router "Default gateway"    
       dns-server "ip"             
       option 67 ascii http://"ip of debian":80/zeroday.py
```

Also the location of the code is in /var/www/html/ But I'm noit sure wheter this will change anything